# The argument type 'Image?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget' because 'Image?'

Tags: flutter

I have this error after updating flutter version,

before updating it works well.

```
The argument type 'Image?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget' because 'Image?' is nullable and 'Widget' isn't.
```

How can I fix this??

```
  Widget levelBtn = FlatButton(
    onPressed: (){
      setState((){
        level++;
        if (level == 2){level = 0;}
      });
    },
    padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
    child: ((){
      if (level == 0){
        return Image.asset("images/LL_BeginnerJa.png",height:constrain.minHeight /414 * 30);
                    
      } else if (level == 1){
        return Image.asset("images/LL_NormalJa.png",height:constrain.minHeight /414 * 30);
      
      } 
    })()
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this syntax and tell me if it works ?

```dart
child: level == 0 ? Image.asset("images/LL_BeginnerJa.png",height:constrain.minHeight /414 * 30) : level == 1 ? Image.asset("images/LL_NormalJa.png",height:constrain.minHeight /414 * 30) : SizedBox(),
```

Whole code

```dart
Widget levelBtn = FlatButton(
  onPressed: () {
    setState((){
      level++;
      if (level == 2){level = 0;}
    });
  },
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
  child: level == 0
      ? Image.asset("images/LL_BeginnerJa.png",
          height: constrain.minHeight / 414 * 30)
      : level == 1
          ? Image.asset("images/LL_NormalJa.png",
              height: constrain.minHeight / 414 * 30)
          : SizedBox(),
);
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but it doesn't work . `lib/main.dart:280:7: Error: Expected an identifier, but got ')'.

Try inserting an identifier before ')'.

      );`

Comment: I have editted it, instead of `;` at the end add a comma `,`

Comment: I edited but error happens, `lib/main.dart:249:35: Error: No named parameter with the name '#3'.
      Widget levelBtn = FlatButton(
`

Comment: By the way it has  like this `child:~?~: ` is this correct?

Comment: I have editted the answer to include the whole widget.

Comment: Wow it works!! I don't understand the meaning though,,,, i need to research. Thank you very much!!

Comment: Bottom line, you had a `()` at the end of your checks indicating that `child` could have a `null` value which is not allowed.

Comment: I see so I try to add `else` to original code and assure to return something , then it works. Thank you for your explanation.

Comment: I bumped into quite similar problem ... `((){
          if (h == 0){
            return "test1";
          }
          else if (h == 1){
            return "test2";
          }
          else {
            return "";
          }
        })()`

Comment: In this case, `h == 0 ? "test" : h ==1 ? "test2" : SizedBox(),`  return `Error: The argument type 'Object' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.
 - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.`

Comment: `SizedBox()` is when you you have to return a `Widget` and instea of null you return just a whitespace. At your case you need `String` so maybe your default `String` value could just be `''`

Comment: It works, My understanding is a bit progress. thank you to your comment